# Adjusting Table Column Width using iText Library in JavaScript, xPages

Tags: javascript, itext, xpages

Using iText Library in xPages, How to adjust column width? If I use table.setWidths(30,10,30), I get the following Error : error: com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException: Script interpreter error, line=52, col=7: Java method 'setWidths(number, number, number)' on java class 'com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable' not found

Comment: What worked at last with one valuable tip from Brian M Moore (Passing parameters as an Array)                                              var table = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable(3); // 3 columns.
var widths:float= [150f, 100f, 150f];
table.setTotalWidth(widths);
table.setLockedWidth(true);
var cell1 = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell(new com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph("Table Cell 1"));
var cell2 = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell(new com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph("Table Cell 2"));
var cell3 = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell(new com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph("Table Cell 3"));

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code into a Java class that only needs to call one function wit the stream and document as parameter

Answer (score 0):

It looks like setWidths expects floats. Does this work?

> table.setWidths(parseFloat(30),parseFloat(10),parseFloat(30))

Comment: Using table.setWidths(parseFloat(30),parseFloat(10),parseFloat(30)), I am still getting the same error.